# Способы перекрыть работу функции.

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста способы перекрыть действие вот этой функции:

```js
$('#sendcustomcake').click(function(){
       createCustomBooking();
    });
```

Уже в другом скрипте и в условии:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
      $('#sendcustomcake').on('click', function() {
            $('.refield').each(function() {
              if ($(this).val() != '') {
                // Если поле не пустое удаляем класс-указание
                $(this).removeClass('empty_field');
              } else {
                // Если поле пустое добавляем класс-указание
                $(this).addClass('empty_field');
                document.getElementById('#sendcustomcake').removeEventListener('click', createCustomBooking);
              }
            });
```

Пытаюсь это сделать с помощью removeEventListener, но это не помогает.

Comment: `off` - отписывает обработчик

Comment: @Grundy, я вас не совсем понял. Что вы имели в виду?

Comment: Ты хочешь удалить обработчик click, в jQuery за это отвечает метод `off`

Comment: @Grundy, `document.getElementById('#sendcustomcake').off('click', createCustomBooking);
              }`
Вот так?

Comment: конечно нет. Определись используешь ты jQuery или нет.

Comment: скорее всего вам будет нужно при назначении вытащить `createCustomBooking` из анонимной функции `function`. то есть `$('#sendcustomcake').click(createCustomBooking);`

Answer (score 1):

Просто сохраните функцию в переменную и используйте переменную для контроля.
Такая же фишка как с setTimeout и clearTimeout.

```js
const click = () => {
    console.log('click');
  }

$('.click').on('click', click);

$('.unclick').click('click', function() {
   console.log('Эвент снят');
   $('.click').off('click', click);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click">Click</button>
<button class="unclick">Unclick</button>
```